# Spectral measures, supports, compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $K:H\rightarrow H$ a compact self-adjoint operator. The spectral measure of $K$ wrt $v\in H$ is uniquely determined by 
$$\langle K^n v,v \rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^n d\mu_v(x)$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. It seems to me that the atoms are strongly related to the eigenvalues, but what is the exact relationship?

Comment: If $\mu_{v}$ has an atom at $\lambda$, then $v$ has a component which is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. That's all you have for a compact operator selfadjoint $K$, with $0$ as the only possible accumulation point.